# Audio errors: Direct firmware load for intel/sof/sof-cml.ri failed with error -2

Tags: debian, audio, intel, firmware

Note this question is on the X1 Carbon 7th Gen with the **10th generation Intel (`Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10710U`)**. Some of the x1c7s have 8th generation intel, and will have different problems; `lshw` reports:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 02c8 (prog-if 80)
```

---

My audio isn't working. I'm not getting any sound or device detection. On the `5.6.0-1-amd64` kernel, I am getting a bunch of errors on `sof-audio-pci`

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i 'sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3'
sof-audio-pci: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040380
sof-audio-pci: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SOF driver
sof-audio-pci: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040380
sof-audio-pci: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
sof-audio-pci: use msi interrupt mode
sof-audio-pci: hda codecs found, mask 5
sof-audio-pci: using HDA machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now
sof-audio-pci: firmware: failed to load intel/sof/sof-cml.ri (-2)
sof-audio-pci: Direct firmware load for intel/sof/sof-cml.ri failed with error -2
sof-audio-pci: error: request firmware intel/sof/sof-cml.ri failed err: -2
sof-audio-pci: error: failed to load DSP firmware -2
sof-audio-pci: error: sof_probe_work failed err: -2
```

Seems it's trying to load a file that doesn't exist, I don't get anything with

```
locate intel/sof/sof-cml.ri
```

I also don't see this in the package `firmware-intel-sound`,

```
➜  ~ apt-file show firmware-intel-sound
firmware-intel-sound: /lib/firmware/intel/IntcSST2.bin
firmware-intel-sound: /lib/firmware/intel/dsp_fw_bxtn.bin
firmware-intel-sound: /lib/firmware/intel/dsp_fw_bxtn_v3366.bin
firmware-intel-sound: /lib/firmware/intel/dsp_fw_cnl.bin
firmware-intel-sound: /lib/firmware/intel/dsp_fw_cnl_v1858.bin
firmware-intel-sound: /lib/firmware/intel/dsp_fw_glk.bin
firmware-intel-sound: /lib/firmware/intel/dsp_fw_glk_v3366.bin
firmware-intel-sound: /lib/firmware/intel/dsp_fw_kbl.bin
firmware-intel-sound: /lib/firmware/intel/dsp_fw_kbl_v3402.bin
firmware-intel-sound: /lib/firmware/intel/dsp_fw_kbl_v3420.bin
firmware-intel-sound: /lib/firmware/intel/dsp_fw_release.bin
firmware-intel-sound: /lib/firmware/intel/dsp_fw_release_v3402.bin
firmware-intel-sound: /lib/firmware/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin
firmware-intel-sound: /lib/firmware/intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-48kHz_i2s_master
firmware-intel-sound: /lib/firmware/intel/fw_sst_22a8.bin
firmware-intel-sound: /usr/share/bug/firmware-intel-sound/presubj
firmware-intel-sound: /usr/share/doc/firmware-intel-sound/changelog.Debian.gz
firmware-intel-sound: /usr/share/doc/firmware-intel-sound/copyright
firmware-intel-sound: /usr/share/metainfo/firmware-intel-sound.metainfo.xml
```

The only output source that shows it the dummy one. Is it possible to get functioning sound with an X1 Carbon 7th Edition that generates this log on boot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note this works with:

```
lspci -nn | grep -i audio
Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02c8]
```

---

- Download this [zip file for the version 1.6 SOF firmware](https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin/archive/v1.6.zip)
- then install it

  ```
    unzip v1.6.zip
    cd sof-bin-1.6
    sudo SOF_VERSION=1.6 ./go.sh
  ```

Then you need to enable it and set the profile, like this.

```
pacmd set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic HiFi
```

Answer (score 8):

The firmware is now in the *firmware-sof-signed* package:

```
apt install firmware-sof-signed
```

Comment: On centos I used `alsa-sof-firmware`. After a few failed attempts to find a solution it ended up being so simple!

Comment: sudo pacman -S sof-firmware for arch

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using Debian unstable.  Recent versions of the Linux kernel (5.5 and newer) have adjusted the sound driver so that it requires firmware whereas it did not before, [which is a bug](https://bugs.debian.org/958737).  However, Debian [has not packaged the firmware yet](https://bugs.debian.org/949019) and the firmware package is known to be behind.  Pulling the firmware from Ubuntu's packages doesn't work because it has an ABI mismatch with the Debian kernel and loading it anyway causes hangs.

You'll need to downgrade to Linux 5.4, convince the Debian developers to fix one of those two bugs, send a patch to Linux to make the driver not fail when it's missing firmware, or use an alternate sound card (e.g., via a Thunderbolt dock).

Comment: For the record, Debian now packages `firmware-sof-signed` (since Bullseye)

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar problem and followed instructions on https://support.system76.com/articles/audio/ What seem to help me was the following commands:

```bsh
sudo apt install --reinstall alsa-base alsa-utils pulseaudio linux-sound-base libasound2
sudo alsa force-reload
```

These commands were done after installation of SOF firmware from https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin/releases

With `pacmd list-cards` I now have `name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic>`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today with this configuration :

**Host**: Alienware m15 R6
**OS**: Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS x86_64
**Kernel**: 5.13.0-39-generic
**CPU**: 11th Gen Intel i7-11800H

```
$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 43c8 (rev 11)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 228e (rev a1)
```

**kern.log**

```
...
kernel: [    5.160734] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: error: request firmware intel/sof/sof-tgl-h.ri failed err: -2
kernel: [    5.160735] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: you may need to download the firmware from https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin/
kernel: [    5.160736] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: error: failed to load DSP firmware: -2
kernel: [    5.160944] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: error: sof_probe_work failed err: -2
...
```

Unlike [Finn Årup Nielsen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/79719/finn-%C3%85rup-nielsen) for my case I downloaded the repository https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin/

```
$ git clone https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin/
```

**WARNING**

In my case it was the sof-tgl-h.ri firmware that I was missing, that's why I copied the v1.7 folder.

and I installed all the drivers in the right folder :

```
$ cd https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin/
$ cd thesofproject

# I created the following folders because they did not exist in my installation

$ sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/intel/sof
$ sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/intel/sof-tplg

# I copied the contents of the following folders into the folders I just created

$ sudo cp v1.7.x/sof-tplg-v1.7/* /lib/firmware/intel/sof-tplg/
$ sudo cp -r v1.7.x/sof-tplg-v1.7/* /lib/firmware/intel/sof-tplg/
```

And now all Work after reboot !

**kern.log**

```
...
kernel: [    5.060963] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DMICs detected in NHLT tables: 2
kernel: [    5.061830] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 1:7:0-47d07
kernel: [    5.061831] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:18:1 Kernel ABI 3:18:0
kernel: [    5.061834] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
kernel: [    5.143748] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 1:7:0-47d07
kernel: [    5.143756] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:18:1 Kernel ABI 3:18:0
kernel: [    5.148469] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Topology: ABI 3:18:1 Kernel ABI 3:18:0
...
```