# No sound device in kernel 5.7 failed to load sof firmware

Tags: debian, kernel, drivers, audio, firmware

I am using parrot os (based on Debian unstable). My audio controller is Intel audio. Here is the lspci:

```
Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 11
    Memory at b629c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b6000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
```

I get follow error in dmesg:

```
[    0.355028] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    9.698733] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    9.698883] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SOF driver
[    9.698893] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    9.699007] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[    9.699092] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    9.705642] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
[   10.052328] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 5
[   10.052330] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: using HDA machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now
[   10.088657] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: firmware: failed to load intel/sof/sof-cml.ri (-2)
[   10.088660] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: Direct firmware load for intel/sof/sof-cml.ri failed with error -2
[   10.088663] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: request firmware intel/sof/sof-cml.ri failed err: -2
[   10.088664] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: failed to load DSP firmware -2
[   10.089021] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: sof_probe_work failed err: -2
```

I see no hw audio device, neither in alsa nor in pulseaudio. I have seen [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/586940/432329) answer, my problem is exact same, but solution doesn't work (I didn't downgrade kernel, and don't want to).
Manually reloading kernel modules also doesn't work. sof firmware is missing but not sure how to install this in Debian (Arch has a package).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing alsa-sof-firmware.

You could install it by following the instructions poster here:

https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin

Comment: I have tried the version 1.5 previously and now 1.6. Installs straight away without any error. But it's not reflected, even after rmmod and modprobe.

Comment: Your kernel does not find the file. Please install the package directly because Debian might contain a very old snapshot of this repo.